# How to save multiple sheets with VBA codes by a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to save multiple sheets from my workbook and saving it in a new file for the filtered data, it will be done for the whole distribution list. So I have made filter function which does the filtering and download button but it only works for the last sheet and unfiltered data.

Here's my code for reference:

```
Sub ExportXLSM()

 Dim myWorksheets() As String 'Array to hold worksheet names to copy
 Dim newWB As Workbook
 Dim CurrWB As Workbook



 Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook

Dim userpath As String
    userpath = Environ("UserProfile")
    
Dim sToday As String
Dim s11 As Worksheet
Set s11 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly_Budget")
    
Dim MyPath As String

Dim MyFileName As String

sToday = s11.Range("A7").Value

 myWorksheets = Split("Summary, Monthly_Budget, History_1", ",")

MyFileName = "KIG_BUDGET_2024_" & sToday & ".xlsm"


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the location and click ok!"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = userpath & " \ Desktop \ "
    '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    
End With

NextCode:
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(myWorksheets) To UBound(myWorksheets) 'Go through entire array
      Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook
      CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
      newWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
      newWB.Close saveChanges:=False
      Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You create a new workbook with every iteration and save it (always with the same name, therefore overwriting the previous created wordbook). Move `Set newWB = Workbooks.Add` before the For-Loop and the Save + Close behind the `Next` so that all sheets are copied into the same workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new workbook for each worksheet and overwriting the previous workbook saved since they all using the same name "MyFileName".

```
   Sub ExportXLSM()
    
 Dim myWorksheets() As String 'Array to hold worksheet names to copy
 Dim newWB As Workbook
 Dim CurrWB As Workbook
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
 Dim r As Long

 Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook

 Dim userpath As String
 userpath = Environ("UserProfile")
    
 Dim sToday As String
 Dim s11 As Worksheet
 Set s11 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly_Budget")
    
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim MyFileName As String

 sToday = s11.Range("A7").Value

 myWorksheets = Split("Summary, Monthly_Budget, History_1", ",")

 MyFileName = "KIG_BUDGET_2024_" & sToday & ".xlsm"

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the location and click ok!"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = userpath & "\Desktop\" ' removed spaces
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Exit if no folder is selected
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With

 Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook

 Dim i As Integer
 For i = LBound(myWorksheets) To UBound(myWorksheets) 
     Set sht = CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i)))
     Set rng = sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     
     newWB.Sheets.Add(After:=newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)).Name = Trim(myWorksheets(i))
     
     For Each rng2 In rng.Areas
         r = newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Cells(newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
         rng2.Copy Destination:=newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Cells(r, 1)
     Next rng2
 Next i

 newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count).Delete 'Delete the initially created sheet

 newWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

 newWB.Close saveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you how do I only copy filtered data?
And this is not working to creat a new file, it says cannot access because File not found!

Comment: see the edit for saving filtered data. Regarding files not found, make sure the file path and names are correct and valid. I suggest you debug the path and name values by using the MsgBox function to display them before trying to save the file.

Comment: try this version

Comment: Oh thank you, I will create a nex question, thanks :)

Comment: Just FYI, for everyone reading it, this macro works perfectly for saving and entire sheet, just doesnt copy the macros to the new one! 
You can add newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete, to delete the initially created list after Save As instead of before, worked for me!
Thanks Horaciux!